# How can I have a dynamic uri segment for a single?

Tags: templating, routes

I am trying to have a dynamic uri segment for a single. I have this uri in the CP settings:

```
offers/listing/{slug}
```

Where `{slug}` is the entryId. For example, `offers/listing/1234`

I have a template at `templates/listing/make-offer.twig`

For the template path i have: `listing/make-offer`

If I navigate to `site.com/offers/listing/1234` I get a 404.

However, if I make a custom route:

```
URI looks like: offers/listing/(slug)
Loads template: listing/make-offer
```

Everything works. The downside is I would like to control the content on the top of the page through the CP.

I realize, this is something more of a channel (which I still get a 404), but this page will never go anywhere. It's a content page at the top with a contact form at the bottom.

Thank you for any suggestions!

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that a **Single** is the right thing to use here (*and I'm not sold on that but I trust your judment*) the following is what I would do to accomplish what you want.

```
// config/routes.php
'offers/listing/(?P<entryId>\d)' => 'listing/make-offer'

// templates/listing/make-offer.twig
{% set entry = entry is defined ? entry : craft.entries.id(entryId) %}
```

**Explanation**

First, we create an [Advanced Route](https://craftcms.com/docs/routing#advanced-routing) to make the (single) `entryId` available to the template that will be loaded when the route matches.

Then, in the template, we set the `entry` variable to either the `entry` that Craft makes available to the template via its own routing or we fetch one explicitly by using the `entryId` passed to the template from the custom route. *Our route may take precedence over default routing, so the `entry is defined` check may be removed and rely instead on `craft.entries.id(entryId)`*

**End Result**

You should be able to navigate to `/offers/listing/1234`, which will load the `templates/listing/make-offer.twig` template with the `entryId` set to `1234`.

Hope this helps, feel free to follow up if something isn't clear.

Comment: Thank you! This makes perfect sense - I'm still getting a 404 though. Is it possible Craft is still reading the uri segment set in the section? It's a required field, so I'm not sure how to override it.

Comment: May need to update the single to use a fixed URI rather than slug?!